# Bluemix / Waston on android (VerifyError)

Tags: java, android, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, visual-recognition

Android rookie here, I am trying to use IBM Bluemix / Watson's VisualRecognition on android studio and getting error as:

> java.lang.VerifyError: com/ibm/watson/developer_cloud/util/CredentialUtils
>
> at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.WatsonService.(WatsonService.java:99)
>
> at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.visual_recognition.v3.VisualRecognition.(VisualRecognition.java:88)

```
VisualRecognition service = new VisualRecognition(VisualRecognition.VERSION_DATE_2016_05_19); 
service.setApiKey("XXXXXXXXXX"); 
ClassifyImagesOptions options = new ClassifyImagesOptions.Builder()
         .images(new File("src/main/res/drawable/img_dummy.png"))
         .build(); 
VisualClassification result = service.classify(options).execute();
```

Everything works including connection to the bluemix app but crashes as it reaches `VisualRecognition`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you add the code you tried that produces this error?

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed in the `v3.0.1`. You just need to update the dependency, you code should be fine.

See the mention of this issue in the [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#version-301) for `v3.0.1`.

> Fix: Error when running in Android and using JDNI